# Execution Failed capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugJavaWithJavac in Ionic 6

Tags: angular, cordova, capacitor, ionic6

I am using Cordova plugin to use fileOpener in the capacitor ionic project. Before this, everything was working fine as I install following packages:

```
npm install @ionic-native/file
npm install cordova-plugin-file
npm install @ionic-native/file-opener
npm install cordova-plugin-file-opener2
```

Here is the error I am facing:

```
  > Configure project :
The RepositoryHandler.jcenter() method has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. JFrog announced JCenter's sunset in 
February 2021. Use mavenCentral() instead. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#jcenter_deprecation
        at build_dcpio6s66acap9ob7gfqiirhb$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall(C:\Project\Ionic\mock-service\android\build.gradle:7)
        (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)
WARNING:: Using flatDirs should be avoided because it doesn't support any meta-data formats.
Currently detected usages:
- repository flatDir used in: project ':app', project ':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins'  
WARNING:: Please remove usages of `jcenter()` Maven repository from your build scripts and migrate your build to other Maven repositories.     
This repository is deprecated and it will be shut down in the future.
See http://developer.android.com/r/tools/jcenter-end-of-service for more information.
Currently detected usages in: root project 'android', project ':app', project ':capacitor-android', ...

> Task :capacitor-android:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
Relying on FileTrees for ignoring empty directories when using @SkipWhenEmpty has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. Annotate the property sourceFiles with @IgnoreEmptyDirectories or remove @SkipWhenEmpty. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/upgrading_version_7.html#empty_directories_file_tree

> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
Relying on FileTrees for ignoring empty directories when using @SkipWhenEmpty has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. Annotate the property sourceDirs with @IgnoreEmptyDirectories or remove @SkipWhenEmpty. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/upgrading_version_7.html#empty_directories_file_tree

> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
C:\Project\Ionic\mock-service\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\main\java\io\github\pwlin\cordova\plugins\fileopener2\FileProvider.java:28: error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
public class FileProvider extends android.support.v4.content.FileProvider {
                                                            ^
C:\Project\Ionic\mock-service\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\main\java\io\github\pwlin\cordova\plugins\fileopener2\FileOpener2.java:119: error: cannot find symbol
                                                path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, cordova.getActivity().getPackageName() + ".fileOpener2.provider", file);
                                                                   ^
  symbol:   method getUriForFile(android.content.Context,java.lang.String,java.io.File)
  location: class io.github.pwlin.cordova.plugins.fileopener2.FileProvider
C:\Project\Ionic\mock-service\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\main\java\io\github\pwlin\cordova\plugins\fileopener2\FileOpener2.java:127: error: cannot find symbol
                                        Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, cordova.getActivity().getPackageName() + ".fileOpener2.provider", file);
                                                               ^
  symbol:   method getUriForFile(android.content.Context,java.lang.String,java.io.File)
  location: class io.github.pwlin.cordova.plugins.fileopener2.FileProvider
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Project\Ionic\mock-service\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\file\AssetFilesystem.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
70 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 69 up-to-date
```

Package.json:

```
     "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.0.0",
    "@capacitor/android": "3.4.1",
    "@capacitor/app": "1.1.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "3.4.1",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "1.1.4",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "1.2.2",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "1.0.8",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "^3.0.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
```

Java Version:

```
java version "1.8.0_321"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_321-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.321-b07, mixed mode)
```

gradle Version:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```

I have tried everything on the internet. Maybe I missed something. Please help me to fix this problem. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling those plugins? Also, what do you have as compileSdkVersion in variables.gradle? Another thing that comes to mind is that you might actually want some earilier gradle versions, like 6*

Comment: I just create a new app and run the app, generate apk and then installed these plugins. here is compileSdkVersion = 30 in variable.gradle

Comment: Hm rading your errors more closely now, the issue might be in `android.support.v4` while you need `AndroidX`. So try using jetifier: `npm install jetifier` and `npx jetify`. Sync the project after that, of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

clean your project

Run **gradlew clean** in andorid directory

Then run below command ,it copies and paste your node module packages in android directory if your using capacitor or cordova or ionic js

**npx cap sync**

important step
run **npx jetify**

if not jetify installed on your local machine **npm install jetifier**

Comment: Is gradle(w) a typo?

Comment: @Tommi no, it is not a typo

Answer (score 1):

I downgraded cordova-plugin-file from version 7 to 6 and it solved the problem!

see detail: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/5602

Answer (score 1):

Nothing of the above answers worked for me. What worked eventually is downgrading Android Build Tools to v5 from v9.

Comment: I think it has some different reasons, no one could solve my issua